# Why my function breaks when I input a large text value?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a function to get a text input value and show it in a label, and it actually works, but when input a large value as "Engenheiro", i get this:

[image: Label breaking insanely]

Here's my code:

```js
  function funcaoProfissao()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById('profissao')
        var b = document.getElementById('lblprofissao');
        b.innerHTML += a.value;
    }
```

```html
                      <input class="inputfield" type="text"  style="font-size: 22pt; color:grey;" name="profissao" id="profissao" onkeyup="funcaoProfissao()"><br>  


 <h3 class="blue negrito">Bacana! Conhecemos e damos consultoria para muitos 
                    <label class="blue negrito" id="lblprofissao"></label> (es/s) que <br>
                    também priorizam viagens e férias como você!! :D
               </h3>
```

I'm new to stackoverflow, so I'm previously sorry for any error or mistake on my question.

Comment: b.innerHTML = a.value; only equal

Comment: **Never assign unsanitized user input to `innerHTML` and the likes!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 5 problems with your code. Only the first is directly responsible for your problem; so you learn a little more from asking here, I've also added another 4 problems with your code, along with an explanation.

1. Instead of appending `+=` you need to reassign `=` the input's value to the label. (`a += 1` actually means `a = a + 1`).
2. **Don't use inline styles**. Put CSS in an external stylesheet.
3. **Don't use inline event listeners**, use `addEventListener` instead. This then also allows you to use the element the listener is bound to as `this` inside your event handler function.
4. Don't listen to `keyup`; `input` elements offer an `input` event which is the far superior event here.
5. **Never** assign unsanitized user input to `innerHTML`!! Use `textContent` for this instead, and use innerHTML only if the string you want to assign should be parsed as HTML.

```js
function funcaoProfissao() {
  document.getElementById('lblprofissao').textContent = this.value;
}

document.getElementById('profissao').addEventListener('input', funcaoProfissao);
```

```css
#profissao {font-size: 22pt; color:grey;}
```

```html
<input class="inputfield" type="text" name="profissao" id="profissao" ><br>
<h3>Bacana! Conhecemos e damos consultoria para muitos
  <label id="lblprofissao"></label> (es/s) que <br> também priorizam viagens e férias como você!! :D
</h3>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the kindness bro, your tips and direction added very much for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `+=` use only `=` like this `b.innerHTML = a.value` to display value:

```js
function funcaoProfissao() {
  var a = document.getElementById('profissao')
  var b = document.getElementById('lblprofissao');
  b.innerHTML = a.value;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputfield" type="text" style="font-size: 22pt; color:grey;" name="profissao" id="profissao"
onkeyup="funcaoProfissao()"><br>


<h3 class="blue negrito">Bacana! Conhecemos e damos consultoria para muitos
<label class="blue negrito" id="lblprofissao"></label> (es/s) que <br>
também priorizam viagens e férias como você!! :D
</h3>
```